# I want to highlight the text in some other color for a delta(difference) found when two strings are compared

Tags: java, html, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

[extentreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVv6M.png)1. I am writing a program to compare two strings using DiffUtils.diff(actualHTML, expHTML). 
2. If there is a difference in two strings, it will print delta
3. I am reporting that delta in the extent report
4. I want to specifically highlight the change part in two strings in some other color while putting in extent report.
eg. String 1 :This is original text and String 2 :This is revised text
original and revised should be in some other color in extent report.
5. Can this be done?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DiffException {

    String filePath=System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test- 
    output/STMExtentReport" + new Date().getTime() + ".html";
    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(filePath);
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("TestName");
    String originalText = "This is original text";
    String revisedText = "This is revised text"; 

    Patch<String> patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalText, revisedText);
    if (patch.getDeltas().size() != 0) {
      for (Delta<String> diffInActAndExpContent : patch.getDeltas())
     {
       System.out.println("delta:" + diffInActAndExpContent);
       test.fail(diffInActAndExpContent.toString()); 
     }
     } else {
       System.out.println("No content mismatch found by 
       ComputeDiffTwoFiles.");
    }
    extent.flush();
}
```

Comment: Yes. it is possible. There is a markup helper method to change the color of the input text.  see extent report doc - http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("This is black! ");
System.err.println("This is red!");
```

But if you run this in cmd, both will be the same color.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the color to reflect in extent report not in console. Also, colored text should only be which is different in 2 strings not the whole string.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Do you still have a problem and need help?

Comment: Added the link to the extentreport. Please click on the link to view Image. I want the "original" and "revised" text to appear in lets say red color.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you are after character difference however DiffUtils provides line difference. you may have to write some logic to find out actual character difference between those 2 strings.
One way is to use StringUtils from apache lang package however it just gives the difference from first unmatched character between 2 strings. you can use below code if it solves your problem or otherwise write the logic to find out actual character difference and use it instead of StringUtils. Extent report is nothing but an html file and can be formatted in whatever way you like, see example to highlight in red color below-

```
    Patch<String> patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalText, revisedText);
    if (patch.getDeltas().size() != 0) {
        for (Delta<String> diffInActAndExpContent : patch.getDeltas()) {
            System.out.println("delta:" + diffInActAndExpContent);
            String diff = StringUtils.difference(diffInActAndExpContent.getOriginal().toString(), diffInActAndExpContent.getRevised().toString());

            test.fail(diffInActAndExpContent.toString().replace(diff, "<font color=red>" + diff + "</font>"));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No content mismatch found by ComputeDiffTwoFiles.");
    }
```